# MS SQL Server 2008 "linked server" to Oracle : schema not showing

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle

I have a Windows 2008 Server (x64) running Microsoft SQL 2008 (x64) and I'm creating a Linked Server connection to an Oracle server.  I'm able to make the connection, but I cannot see any information regarding which schema a table belongs to.

In SQL 2005, my linked servers show the schema information as I would expect.

Does anyone know how to resolve this issue?  Is it an issue with the provider, OraOLEDB.Oracle?

Any help or pointers would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

@Boojiboy - When you are looking at the tables via a linked server, there used to be a column for what schema.  It appears that in the latest the new Oracle OLEDB drivers don't show this information any longer.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like sp_tables_ex will do the trick, it came from the below article.

> --verify tables OK exec sp_tables_ex @table_server = 'LINKED_ORA',
>   @table_schema='MySchema'
>
> @table_schema is optional.  If not
>   provided, you will get a list of all 
>   tables in all schemas.

http://it.toolbox.com/blogs/daniel-at-work/linking-sql-server-2005-to-oracle-26791

Answer (score 0):

Also in the SQL 08 > Server Objects > Providers
make sure your OraOLEDB.Oracle provider is allowing inprocessing